# Is it possible to compare two multi-word integers with only one comparison per word?

Tags: c, performance, numbers, comparison

This question is independent of language, but I'll use C since that's what I'm coding it in.

Given two integers `a` and `b` that span `n_word` words each, what is the most efficient way of comparing these multi-word numbers, for example determining `a < b`? (†)

As a concrete example, we could consider `a` and `b` to be 8-bit integer arrays of length `n_word` which each represent one `8*n_word`-bit integer (and assume big-endian ordering).(††) Alternatively, the question can be phrased using regular old decimal numbers, e.g., `a = 456` where `a[0]` is the first digit (4) etc.

I have the following code which works, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get rid of one of the two comparisons:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n_word; ++i) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) {
        i = n_word + 1;   /* use as magic number to indicate that a > b */
        break;
    }
    else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Then the result is determined by the value of `i` after the loop:

```
if i < n_word,  then a < b
if i > n_word,  then a > b
if i == n_word, then a == b
```

But I don't actually want/need to distinguish between all three cases; collapsing two of the cases into one is perfectly fine. However, if I just remove, e.g., the `>` comparison without changing anything else, then (in the decimal example) `a = 200` and `b = 123` (where `a > b`) would evaluate to the same as `a = 100` and `b = 123` (where `a < b`), which is clearly incorrect. Replacing `<` with `<=` in the loop seems to be equally bogus.

---

† Though `a > b` or either of their converses would also be acceptable.

†† And no, of course I'm not *actually* trying to compare two 32-bit integers, but more like 10 32-bit integers that form one very long integer beyond the reach of any native types.

Comment: There is nothing built into the language for this, performance optimization is highly sensitive to context, about which you have provided no information, and, if the target processor has a compare instruction that provides separate less than, equal to, and greater than information, the compiler is likely to use it given the code shown, provided optimization is enabled.

Comment: _"10 32-bit integers that form one very long integer beyond the reach of any native types"_ and assuming _big endian_: What about `memcmp`? It should work if the big ints are unsigned. `uint32_t a[10] = {1}, b[10] = {2};` `printf("%d\n", memcmp(a, b, sizeof a));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I hadn't heard of `memcmp` yet, that actually sounds very useful—but unfortunately the system is actually little-endian (much to my chagrin), I was just using big-endianness to not over-complicate the example I gave... It seems that getting `memcmp` is not of much use then?

Comment: @MrArsGravis You'd have to reverse the bytes (not the order of the `uint32_t`s) in both arrays before using `memcmp` on a little endian system. Reversing them could perhaps be quick too but perhaps it's better to then write a `memcmp`-like function that compares `uint8_t`s from the end and back to the beginning and hope for the optimizer to do a good job.

Comment: Note that GMP can work with large numbers very efficiently and implement such thing. Beside this, reversing bytes is very fast on x86-64 platform since there is an instruction for that. SIMD instructions can also be used to speed up the computation (though the probability that two numbers are nearly equal is certainly small). A branchless implementation should solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your concern (that there is more than one comparison) is unfounded.

The `ASM` instruction `CMP` sets the FLAG register, and both conditional jumps are performed based on those flags.

Please see https://godbolt.org/z/rfxP185Mf